# How to remove Duplicates(Old Objects) from arraylist

Tags: java, collections

I have a `Check Entity` where I have three attributes including Id and am using the Id for hashcode inorder to use and check duplicates.

Now Duplicates are getting removed using below code

```
Set<Check> unique = new LinkedHashSet<Check>(l);
List<Check>  finalLst= new java.util.ArrayList<Check>();
finalLst.addAll(unique);
```

In Output

These three are coming as result(c1,c2 and c3) , but I want (c4,c5 and c6).

```
Check c1 = new Check(1,"one");
Check c2 = new Check(2,"two");
Check c3 = new Check(3,"three");


    Check c4 = new Check(1,"one");
    Check c5 = new Check(2,"two");
    Check c6 = new Check(3,"three");
```

Output am getting Now  :

```
    id :1 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.311
    id :2 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
    id :3 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
    id :1 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
    id :2 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.345
    id :3 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.345
1 :: 2013-04-30 10:42:34.311
2 :: 2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
3 :: 2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
```

Output am Expecting :

```
    id :1 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.311
    id :2 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
    id :3 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
    id :1 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
    id :2 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.345
    id :3 ::2013-04-30 10:42:34.345
1 :: 2013-04-30 10:42:34.344
2 :: 2013-04-30 10:42:34.345
3 :: 2013-04-30 10:42:34.345
```

**My Whole code goes here :**

```
package test.collection;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class RemoveDuplicateInArrayList 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Check c1 = new Check(1,"one");
        Check c2 = new Check(2,"two");
        Check c3 = new Check(3,"three");


        Check c4 = new Check(1,"one");
        Check c5 = new Check(2,"two");
        Check c6 = new Check(3,"three");

        List<Check> l = new java.util.ArrayList<Check>();
        l.add(c1);
        l.add(c2);
        l.add(c3);
        l.add(c4);
        l.add(c5);
        l.add(c6);

        List<Check>  finalLst= removeDuplicates(l);
        Iterator<Check> iter = finalLst.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            Check temp = iter.next();
            System.out.println(temp.getId()+" :: "+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").format(temp.getCreationTme()));
        }

    }
    public static List<Check> removeDuplicates(List<Check> l)
    {
        Set<Check> unique = new LinkedHashSet<Check>(l);
        List<Check>  finalLst= new java.util.ArrayList<Check>();
        finalLst.addAll(unique);
        return finalLst;
    }
}

class Check
{
    public Check(int id,String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.creationTme = new Date();
        System.out.println("id :"+this.id+" ::"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").format(this.getCreationTme()));
    }
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date creationTme;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Date getCreationTme() {
        return creationTme;
    }
    public void setCreationTme(Date creationTme) {
        this.creationTme = creationTme;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj instanceof Check && ((Check)obj).id == this.id)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: down-voters if you have sense make comment !!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for all your Answers............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use map instead

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RemoveDuplicateInArrayList 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Check c1 = new Check(1,"one");
        Check c2 = new Check(2,"two");
        Check c3 = new Check(3,"three");


        Check c4 = new Check(1,"one");
        Check c5 = new Check(2,"two");
        Check c6 = new Check(3,"three");

        Map<Integer, Check> map = new HashMap<Integer, Check>();
        map.put( c1.getId() , c1 );
        map.put( c2.getId() , c2 );
        map.put( c3.getId() , c3 );
        map.put( c4.getId() , c4 );
        map.put( c5.getId() , c5 );
        map.put( c6.getId() , c6 );

        System.out.println( map );
    }

}

class Check
{
    public Check(int id,String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.creationTme = new Date();
        System.out.println("id :"+this.id+" ::"+this.getCreationTme().getTime());
    }
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Date creationTme;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Date getCreationTme() {
        return creationTme;
    }
    public void setCreationTme(Date creationTme) {
        this.creationTme = creationTme;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj instanceof Check && ((Check)obj).id == this.id)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        final String TAB = "    ";

        String retValue = "";

        retValue = "Check ( "
            + "id = " + this.id + TAB
            + "name = " + this.name + TAB
            + "creationTme = " + this.creationTme.getTime() + TAB
            + " )";

        return retValue;
    }


}
```

PS: I am not the downvoter :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `Comparable` interface & override the `compareTo()`method in your `check` class like this:-

```
class Check implements Comparable<Check>{
```

and the `compareTo()` method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Check o) {
    if(creationTme.after(o.getCreationTme())){
        return -1;
    }else if(creationTme.before(o.getCreationTme())){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And before removing the duplicates, you can just `Sort` your list like this:-

```
Collections.sort(l);
List<Check> finalLst = removeDuplicates(l);
```

Comment: I have used set here check my question once again>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: @sunleo -  I was hasty in reading your question! Check my updated answer now!

Answer (score 0):

Hashset works the following way:
If you try to add an Object, it's hashcode is computed. If the hashcode is already present in the map, nothing will happen (why should it? Hashcode - and therefore equivalent Object - is already in there)
So your output is completely reasonable :)

If you want to have an overwritehashset, I'd suggest writing your own.

Take a class with a private hashset.
add methode first checks if hashcode is already present, if yes: remove the value from the set and add the new one. If no: just add it.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your method a bit , so that you can get the expected result. Basically you wanted the latest ones. So here it is :

```
public static List<Check> removeDuplicates(List<Check> l)
    {
        Collections.reverse(l);
        Set<Check> unique = new LinkedHashSet<Check>(l);
        List<Check>  finalLst= new java.util.ArrayList<Check>();
        finalLst.addAll(unique);
        Collections.reverse(finalLst);
        return finalLst;
    }
```

Try this , it will work